# Flutter I used two GesturdetectorButtons but it won't show my designed AppPage

Tags: flutter, text, combinations, gesturedetector

guys so my question is how I can design the next Page after pressing on GesturDetector.
I already coded something (2.Code) and befor I added the scond Gesturdetector it was also showen but the problem was that the title don't changed now the title is changing right but it's only the title and now AppBar nothing.
I hope you understand my problem and you can help me.

For the first Page

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:essen/Rezept.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Sachen.dart';
export 'Rezept.dart';




class Categories extends StatelessWidget{
  final String name;
  Categories(this.name)
  ;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF4caf50),
        title: Text(name),
        foregroundColor: const Color(0xFFeceff1),
      ),
      body: const DicePage(),
    );
  }
}

class DicePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DicePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DicePageState createState() => _DicePageState();
}

class _DicePageState extends State<DicePage> {
  int PicNumber = 1;
  int PiNumber =1;

  void changeDiceNumber() {
    setState(() {
      PicNumber = Random().nextInt(4) +1;
      PiNumber = Random().nextInt(4) +1;
    });
  }



  final List<Sachen> infoBank = [
    Sachen(title: "Schoko-Bowl", image: Image.asset("Images/frue1.png"), text: '-Mehl'),
    Sachen(title: "Smoothie-Bowl", image: Image.asset("images/frue2.png"), text: '-Zucker'),
    Sachen(title: "Porridge", image: Image.asset("images/frue3.png"), text: '-Milch'),
    Sachen(title: "Porridge", image: Image.asset("images/frue4.png"), text: '-Eier'),
    Sachen(title: "Schoko Mousse", image: Image.asset("images/frue5.png"),text: '-Butter'),

  ];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Card(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 35, 50, 0),
            elevation: 15,
            color: const Color(0xFF4caf50),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 80,
              width: 180,
              child: Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 18),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => Rezept('Dein Frühstück',
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Center(
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).push(
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Text(infoBank[PicNumber].title,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        child: Text(infoBank[PicNumber].title,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      PicNumber++;
                    });
                    changeDiceNumber();
                    print('LeftDiceNumber = $PicNumber');
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: 415,
                    width: 350,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 20, 10, 20),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(
                        width: 3,
                        color: Colors.grey.shade700,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: FittedBox(
                      child: infoBank[PicNumber].image,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For the second Page where I designed everything but nothing is showen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Sachen.dart';
import 'dart:math';


class Rezept extends StatelessWidget{
  final String rezept;
  Rezept(this.rezept);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF4caf50),
        title: Text(rezept),
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        titleTextStyle: const TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 20,
        ),
      ),
      body: RezeptPage(),
    );
  }
}



class RezeptPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const RezeptPage ({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RezeptPageState createState() => _RezeptPageState();
}

class _RezeptPageState extends State<RezeptPage> {
  int PiNumber = 1;


  void changeDiceNumber() {
    setState(() {
      PiNumber = Random().nextInt(4) +1;
    });
  }


  final List<Sachen> infoBank = [
    Sachen(title: "Schoko-Bowl", image: Image.asset("Images/frue1.png"), text: '-Mehl'),
    Sachen(title: "Smoothie-Bowl", image: Image.asset("images/frue2.png"), text: '-Zucker'),
    Sachen(title: "Porridge", image: Image.asset("images/frue3.png"), text: '-Milch'),
    Sachen(title: "Porridge", image: Image.asset("images/frue4.png"), text: '-Eier'),
    Sachen(title: "Schoko Mousse", image: Image.asset("images/frue5.png"),text: '-Butter'),

  ];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 15, 10, 15),
            child: Card(
              elevation: 8,
              child: ListTile(
                title: Center(
                  child: Text(infoBank[PiNumber].title,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 350,
          height: 500,
          child: Card(
            elevation: 5,
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 20),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 10, 0),
              child: RichText(text: const TextSpan(
                text: 'Zutaten:',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 22.0,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                  decorationThickness: 2.0,
                ),
                children: <TextSpan>[
                  TextSpan(
                    text: '\n\n-Mehl' '\n-Zucker' '\n-Milch' '\n-Eier' '\n-Butter',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextSpan(
                    text: '\n\nZubereitung:',
                  ),
                  TextSpan(
                    text: '\n\n-Zuerst vermischen wir alles' '\n-Anschließend wird es in der Pfanne angebraten' '\n-Zuletzt mit Schokolade bestreichen und genießen',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Categorie.dart]
[image: After pressing GesturDetector]

Comment: I think you are not using `Scafold ` widget that's why it's showing black screen check your code again.

Comment: In second page you are really missing Scaffold as @prototype86 saying. You are pushing new route so all the "scaffoldnes" is gone and you have to design that second on its own

Comment: First of all thank ypu for your help and could you show me where exactly because I am not really sure where you mean I should put it